# Auth::login($user) laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy usando `Auth::login($user);` para loguear manualmente
*usando fluent / querybuilder*

> Ejemplo

```
    $count = DB::table('users')
             ->where('username', '=', $username)
             ->where('password', '=', $password)
             ->count();


    if($count > 0 ){
         $user = DB::table('users')
                 ->where('login', '=', $username)
                 ->where('password', '=', $password)
                 ->get();

         Auth::login($user);
         return redirect("/");

   }else{
      return "datos incorrectos";
   }
```

**lo que laravel dice:**

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must
>   be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, array
>   given

hay alguna forma de hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Hola @Devil. Este no es el típico foro de internetdonde hay hilo y se cierran. Aquí una pregunta no se cierra, siempre puede admitir nuevas respuestas por parte de la comunidad. Te recomiendo visitar el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Si deseas usar el sistema de autenticación de Laravel debes usar sus interfaces, de hecho en general no es una buena práctica usar la facade DB a menos que sea estrictamente necesario.

Para que funcione debes pasar un objeto que sea instancia de Authenticatable, tal y como lo muestra la definición del método:

```
public function login(AuthenticatableContract $user, $remember = false)
```

---

En ese orden de ideas lo mejor sería usar Eloquent, algo como esto en el modelo:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class User implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    protected table = 'users';
}
```

Login

```
$user = User::where('login', $username)->where('password', $password)->first();
```

---

Si definitivamente NO deseas usar Eloquent, entonces extiende la clase `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard`, más especificamente el método login por medio de un ServiceProvider.

Si no funciona aún entonces deberás crear tu propio sistema de autenticación, reemplazando el ServiceProvider actual, a partir de config/app.php y config/auth.php

Comment: no hay una forma simple de autenticar sin tanta vuelta? parece mas facil crearse un nuevo framework mvc desde cero , yo lo unico que busco es saltarme el auth:attempt y asi saltarme otras cosas que me llevan a auth::check donde sale bcrypt y me encripta los password como el quiere

Comment: La verdad la forma sencilla es utilizar el método de autenticación de Laravel, así como cualquier otro framework. ¿Para qué usar un framework si deseas algo 100% custom?

Comment: mmm entonces para este caso voy a tener que usar otro framework , incluso wordpress resulta mas amigable pero no quiero usar wordpress ni php crudo, hay algun framework que me sirva para mi caso o tendre que costruirme uno a partir de las dependecias de symfony?

Comment: Infortunadamente no tengo respuesta para esa pregunta, no conozco todos los frameworks existentes. Puedes probar Lumen que es una versión reducida de Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

get() devuelve un array, tenes que pedir la info con first(), que te da un objeto

$user = DB::table('users')->where('login', '=', $username)->where('password', '=', $password)->first();